# Galaxy S7 Android 8 Oreo; keyboard shortcuts/settings/dictionary backup possible...?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, home-screen-shortcuts

Is it possible to backup **Samsung** keyboard shortcuts, settings and any additions you make to the dictionary on the Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 8 Oreo?

TIA,

Ivan.